# django admin passing arguments to a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I would like to know how to pass parameters to a django model form custom class

for example I have something like this:

```
class DealAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EscapeToRelaxForm
```

and I want to do semthing like this:

```
class DealAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EscapeToRelaxForm(category='relax', region='NA')
```

any idea how to do that..??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override the `get_form` method in your Admin subclass.